Type 'MetalViewRepresentable' does not conform to protocol 'NSViewRepresentable'
Error
Type 'MetalViewRepresentable' does not conform to protocol 'NSViewRepresentable'
and
Reference to invalid associated type 'NSViewType' of type 'MetalViewRepresentable'
Question
Not sure why this is happening, but I think issue is not the code but something with my targets I think. I've set up a brand new MacOS application and pasted this code and it builds perfectly fine, but for some reason in my main app it's not working.
To Reproduce

Create a MacOS App
Copy Paste

struct MetalViewRepresentable: ViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var metalView: MTKView
  func makeNSView(context: Context) -> some NSView {
    metalView
  }
  func updateNSView(_ uiView: NSViewType, context: Context) {
  }
}

class Context {} // Comment this line out to fix


On which line is the error?

Line 1. struct MetalViewRepresentable: NSViewRepresentable

It's because I had a class named Context. This seems like a bigger bug but maybe someone can tell me more. This bug only exists for MacOS target.

Have you tried renaming the Context type in the functions to Self.Context or possibly MetalViewRepresentable.Context?

I tried your suggestion func makeNSView(context: Self.Context) and it still doesn't work. It did remove the second error but the first error is still there.

Oh actually, sorry I didn't realize there was 2 Contexts. I did it for both and that actually did fix it - Jeez, I literally commented out every file I had like 50+ files to figure out that bug.

That's not a bug. It's weird though that Xcode doesn't take the "closest" reference, in this case Self.Context over your other Context. Never encountered this during iOS development, so might be related to macOS builds only
